# Neo4j Drawbacks

Tags: database, lucene, neo4j

So I am putting together a report on Neo4j and it's potential advantages over your average relational database.  In my research, I've encountered a couple issues that might not make Neo4j the best choice at the present for a public server application. Namely:

- Neo4j uses Apache Lucene, which treats all data as text.  This makes purely integer data queries much slower than they need to be.
- Neo4j has no user management built in.  All security must be done at the application level.

My question is whether my research is outdated and these issues have solutions.  I know that community and support for Neo4j and other graph databases is growing fast.  Anyone with knowledge on the current state of Neo4j could really help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your point #1 is incorrect, point #2 is still true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reply to your first bullet:

By using ValueContext you can tell Lucene to index it numerically and also to query by numeric value or numeric range. See for example https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/lucene-index/src/test/java/org/neo4j/index/impl/lucene/TestLuceneIndex.java#L622

Comment: Wish you could do this with auto indexes!

Answer (score 4):

As for the second bullet, it appears that version 2.2 (currently at M3) introduces true user management. See http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-milestone-1-release/ for a basic overview of the new features. Note that this is not a production ready release.